# JavaScript closures and name clobbering

Tags: javascript, namespaces, scope, closures

Are variables defined inside an inner function that have the same name as a variable in an outer function isolated from the outer variable?

```
function() {
    var myTest = "hi there";
    ( function( myTest ) {
        myTest = "goodbye!";
    } )();
    console.log( myTest ); // myTest should still be "hi there" here, correct?
}
```

Naturally if I didn't *declare* `myTest` inside the inner function it would create a closure and modify the original. I just want to make sure that variables declared within an inner function are always isolated to that function even if their name may conflict with an outer scope.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, they effectively do. Each function creates a new scope, and the closest scope in which a requested variable is declared always takes precedence. No exceptions.

Comment: @chaiguy: Yes, sorry. Mixed up my words there a bit.

Comment: this method also avoids scope lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness. In these *very similar* examples, here is what happens with no parameter

```
var x = 'a';
( function(  ) {   //note that there is no parameter here
    x = 'b';
    alert('inner:'+x); //b
} )();
alert('outer:'+x); //b
```

and a var with the same name

```
var x = 'a';
( function(  ) {
    var x = 'b';
    alert('inner:'+x); //b
} )();
alert('outer:'+x); //a
```